# Aligned memory allocator: memory corruption (game engine architecture[Jason Gregory])

Tags: c++, memory, architecture, game-engine, memory-alignment

I was just reading [Game Engine Architecture by Jason Gregory](https://encrypted.google.com/books/about/Game_Engine_Architecture.html?id=LJ20tsePKk4C) S.212, when I stumbled on the code where he is allocating aligned memory. I think he is producing a memory corruption and a tried it by myself with the following code:

```
void* myalloc( unsigned size )
{
    // this will not return a valid memory address but its ok since
    // it will never be dereferenced! its just to check what if a real malloc would
    // return this obviously UNALIGNED memory address
    return reinterpret_cast<void*>( 0x00001 );
}
void* allocatedAligned( unsigned size_bytes, unsigned alignment )
{
    unsigned expandedSize_bytes = size_bytes + alignment;
    unsigned rawAddress = (unsigned)myalloc( expandedSize_bytes );

    unsigned mask = alignment - 1;
    unsigned misalignment = rawAddress & mask;
    unsigned adjustment = alignment - misalignment;

    unsigned alignedAddress = rawAddress + adjustment;

    unsigned* ptrAdjustment = reinterpret_cast<unsigned*>( alignedAddress - 4 );
    //*ptrAdjustment = adjustment; //Corruption here
    //return reinterpret_cast<unsigned*>( alignedAddress ); this is what jasons function normally returns
    return ptrAdjustment;
}

int main()
{
    void* ptr = allocatedAligned( 4, 4 );
    std::cout << ptr << std::endl; // this shouldn't print an address lower than 0x0001
    return 1;
}
```

the alignment works as it should be, but I have to object the line `*ptrAdjustment = adjustment` as it IMHO corrupts the memory. It writes memory before the address received from myalloc() or am I wrong?
`main()` should not print any address smaller than that returned by myalloc() ?!

I am looking forward to your answers, thanks!

Note: This example is about: Where would memory be written, not about: `myalloc()` returns wrong memory....

(my changes on the code:

- used unsigned instead of `U32`
- used `myalloc()` instead of `allocateUnaligned()`
- c++ casting instead of c-style
  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is broken. If the malloc would return already properly aligned address, say 0 and you request 8 byte aligned address, the code will return address 4, which is obviously wrong. The following line should be removed:

`unsigned* ptrAdjustment = reinterpret_cast<unsigned*>( alignedAddress - 4 );`

And the code should just return alignedAddress:

`return reinterpret_cast<unsigned*>( alignedAddress );`

(also it should be `void*` not `unsigned*` and he should be using `size_t` not `unsigned`). If you want the code to return the original malloc() address in case it's already properly aligned, you could simply change the above line to:

`return reinterpret_cast<void*>(misalignment?alignedAddress:rawAddress);`

Also to be pedantic, there should be assert in the function to validate that the alignment is power-of-2, e.g. `assert((alignment&(alignment-1))==0);`

Comment: The code may be broken but 1. the poster made modifications to the code from the book. 2. the original intent of the book author is not indicated by the original poster here and therefore the suggested fix doesnt work.  ptrAdjustment deliberately always returns at 2 bytes forward of the raw address and those "wasted" are intended to store by how much the address was adjusted so that when the adjusted address is freed using freeAligned() the offset can be looked up there to see how much to really free.  The author specfically says never to use this function if 1 byte alignment is needed also.

Answer (score 1):

Working through the math of your example:

`size_bytes` is 4 and `unsigned alignment` is 4

`expandedSize_bytes` is set to 8

`mask` is set to 3

`misalignment` is set to 1 & 3 which is 1.

`adjustment` is set to 4 - 1 which is 3.

`alignedAddress` is set to 0x0001 + 3 which is 4.

`ptrAdjustment` is set to 4 - 4 which is 0x0000.

So yes, that commented out line would try to write to memory outside the allocated area if your example scenario actually happened.

On the other hand, if the raw address is already aligned on at least 4 and the requested alignment is 4 or larger, then it looks like the math works out so that there will be no invalid memory access. Maybe the author assumed that would be the case. Or maybe he only tested his math against those kind of scenarios. After all, with modern C/C++ malloc itself should only be returning addresses with reasonable alignment already.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I did not try it with malloc because as you already stated you fetch addresses with reasonable alignment. maybe his intention was to realign a ie. 4byte aligned address to 16 or 128 byte aligned....

Answer (score 0):

I have not read the book mentioned by you and this particular techniques. But I think there is some fundamental concepts needs to be mentioned to answer your question.

> but I have to object the line *ptrAdjustment = adjustment as it IMHO
>   corrupts the memory

This is not an example of memory corruption as above program does not allocate memory in the sample code. The above program crashes at the line

```
*ptrAdjustment = adjustment;
```

because ***ptrAdjustment*** pointer does not have valid memory(NULL pointer) received from the heap memory allocator. Because in the above code we have not allocated any memory.

I think we need to change the above code to allocate the address from malloc() API. This way ***myalloc*** would return the valid memory.

```
void* myalloc( unsigned size )
{
    return reinterpret_cast<void*>( malloc(size) );
}
```

However we should not bother(until absolutely required) much about the alignment of address as memory allocator does return the address which would be properly aligned(8 or 16 byte).

Additionally your program must need to write the ***myfree()*** kind of function to free the memory allocated by ***myalloc()***. This is equally serious problem as the memory corruption.

In C++ program, we should avoid to use the raw pointer and instead start using the [STL container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) and [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

Comment: i know that the myalloc is NOT returning valid memory ;) Its just about the print in the main... if the malloc would return valid memory, IMO it would corrupt memory.... myAlloc is just a "hack" to see what if.....

Comment: @lifeOfPI: As I have mentioned that i do not have the access to the book mentioned by you. Hence I do not know what is the purpose of the author to write custom memory allocator to get the memory address aligned to particular value. But in summary any access to the memory beyond requested size in program lead to memory corruption.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that are all information I do not ask for... do not care about container, free, malloc etc... it is just about: Is it a corruption yes/no